# Uniswap V2 router contract call fails with TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

Tags: etherscan, evm, python

The scan link is here: https://wemixscan.com/tx/0x717a6385a15f896a08dc9e6ca3980cdd7443ca8a88a0ab5944522c61200c06a8

I'm trying to swap between WWEMIX(Wrapped Wemix token) for WEMIX$ (Wemix dollar) by calling on the weswap_router contract as shown in the code below:

```
url_wemix = "https://api.wemix.com"
url_testwemix = "https://api.test.wemix.com"
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(url_wemix))

# Account address
account_address = '0x8c22e86fcfaee1e1d32eba1e8d6b2e204a6c2413'
checked_address = w3.to_checksum_address(account_address)
private_key = 'empty just to upload into stackexchange'

# Contract addresses
weswap_router = "0x80a5a916fb355a8758f0a3e47891dc288dac2665"
wemix_wemixdollar_pool = "0x00caEc2e118AbC4c510440A8D1ac8565Fec0180C"
wemixdollar = "0x8e81fcc2d4a3baa0ee9044e0d7e36f59c9bba9c1"
wwemix = "0x7d72b22a74a216af4a002a1095c8c707d6ec1c5f"
pool_checked = w3.to_checksum_address(wemix_wemixdollar_pool)
wwemix_checked = w3.to_checksum_address(wwemix)
wemixdollar_checked = w3.to_checksum_address(wemixdollar)

# Contract details
checked_contract = w3.to_checksum_address(weswap_router)
contract_abi = simplejson.loads(open(os.path.join(project_path, 'weswap_abi.json')).read())
#contract = w3.eth.contract(address=checked_contract, abi=weswap_router_contract_abi)
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=checked_contract, abi=contract_abi)
wwemix__abi = simplejson.loads(open(os.path.join(project_path, 'wwemix_abi.json')).read())
wwemix_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=wwemix_checked, abi=wwemix__abi)

# Input values for WEMIX to WEMIX$
input = 10/(10**18) # Input of WEMIX to swap to WEMIX$
output = 0 # Minimum output for swapping WEMIX to WEMIX$
amountIn = w3.to_wei(input, 'ether')
amountOutMin = w3.to_wei(output, 'ether')
from_address = wwemix_checked
to_address = wemixdollar_checked
path = [from_address, to_address]
to = pool_checked # recipient of function call
deadline = int(time.time()) + 3600

amounts = contract.functions.getAmountsOut(amountIn, path).call()
print(amounts)
nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(checked_address)
# Get approval for WWEMIX token transfer
isApproved = wwemix_contract.functions.approve(checked_contract, amountIn).build_transaction({
    'from': checked_address,
    'nonce': nonce})
print(isApproved)

# Function call for swap WEMIX to WEMIX$ 
function = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    amountIn,
    amountOutMin, 
    path, 
    to, 
    deadline
)

# Build transaction
tx = function.build_transaction({
    'from': checked_address,
    'nonce': nonce,
    #'value': w3.to_wei(0.7, 'ether'),
    #'gasPrice': w3.to_wei(140, 'gwei'),
    'maxFeePerGas': w3.to_wei(102, 'gwei'),
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': w3.to_wei(101, 'gwei'),
    'gas': 500000
})

# Sign transaction
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key=private_key)

# Send transaction
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)

# print transaction
print('Transaction Hash:', tx_hash.hex())
```

I have gone through the stackexchange on the same issue, tried token approval, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. Where could the issue be coming from?

At first, it didn't go through because I didn't have WWEMIX, but I got that taken care of but not sure where the error is coming from.
Essentially, I was trying to make a transaction like the one below:
https://wemixscan.com/tx/0x1bb9b2d47f6b217f88898efa81c8ce7aefb12ce6cac53c489bd1ce3d67288e98

I do have WWEMIX in my address as well.

EDIT:
When I check other bots out there trying to do the same transaction, it seems that they are not doing approval at all as based on their transaction data:
https://wemixscan.com/tx/0xc2db2dfa8ebb121fff8b3a25bffc2efca5109373c625efb08f4da5108bb25aec

Comment: A good searcher isn't likely to waste gas on approvals or routers, they will transfer on to a pool and call the low level swap function directly. If using a router that will move your token then you will need to approve.